How do I set an account's balance on the Relay chain using Zombienet config?
[relaychain]
chain = "rococo-local"

[[relaychain.nodes]]
name = "alice"
validator = true

[[relaychain.nodes]]
name = "bob"
validator = true

[[parachains]]
id = 2000
default_command = "./target/release/parachain-template-node"

[[parachains.collators]]
name = "collator-01"

Above is my config, how do I set an account's balance on genesis using a zombienet config?

network.toml
[relaychain]
chain = "paseo-local"

[relaychain.runtime_genesis_patch.balances]
balances = [
    ["5EAGYXoTkZs4rMefBnf1SbruKr3FN19yzZ24LUhiE2ah3kz2", 1152921504606846976],
]

[[relaychain.nodes]]
name = "alice"
validator = true

[[relaychain.nodes]]
name = "bob"
validator = true

[[relaychain.nodes]]
name = "charlie"
validator = true

Using Pop CLI: pop up parachain -f network.toml
